# Boost not found when installing dlib, but its actually installed

Tags: opencv, installation, boost, cmake, dlib

Im trying to install dlib for few cv2 projects, but I have problems installing it.I made everything without problem but when I wanted to finally do the `python setup.py install` It showed me this error message: `Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) (found suitable version "1.79.0", minimum required is "1.41.0")` 
I mean why doesnt it work when it sees my installed Boost 1.79...

Does somebody know how to fix it guys?
Thank you anyways:)

Answer (score 2):

From error log it looks like boost libraries are found, but it's missing specific boost library to integrate with [python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html)

You have not mentioned which OS you are using for debian & it's derivatives

`sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev` or if you are installing specific version of boost `sudo apt-get install libboost-python1.79-dev` should install the python module.

If boost is built from sources, during bootstrapping enable python libs to be built

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python,filesystem,serialization
```

for list of boost libs can be built

```
./bootstrap.sh --show-libraries
```

Comment: Your OS & release version?

Comment: Ok, I got finally boost downloaded the way you wrote me, but when installing dlib I again got few error messages - missing python, python3 and python-py35. Now Im even more confused lol

Comment: I have ubuntu 20.04. And my cmake library is version 3.22.4 if that could help

Comment: on 20.04 default boost lib version is 1.71, see - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/libboost-dev. How was 1.79 installed ? Are you ok to downgrade boost ?

Comment: Yeah, I also realised that and I already have 1.71 but still the same error

Comment: It's better to stick to one version, try uninstalling boost 1.79.